In Pandas, how to reference and use a value from a dictionary based on column AND index values in a dataframe?
I've data about how my times people are sick in certain locations (location A and B) at certain times (index of dates). I need to divide each value by the population in that location (column) AND at that time (index), which references a separate dictionary.
Eg dataframe:
import pandas as pd
data = [{'A': 1, 'B': 3}, {'A': 2, 'B': 20}, {'A': "Unk", 'B': 50}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[pd.to_datetime("2019-12-31")
                               , pd.to_datetime("2020-12-30")
                               , pd.to_datetime("2020-12-31")])
Out:
            A   B
2019-12-31  1   3
2020-12-30  2   20
2021-12-31  Unk 50

Population dictionary (location_year):
dic = {"A_2019": 100, "B_2019": 200, "A_2020": 120, "B_2020": 150}

While it's not necessary to have the output in the same df, the output I'm trying to achieve would be:
            A   B    A1     B1
2019-12-31  1   3   0.01    0.015
2020-12-30  2   20  0.017   0.133
2021-12-31  Unk 50  nan     0.333

I've tried lots of different approaches, but almost always get an unhashable type error.
for col in df.columns:
     df[col + "1"] = df[col]/dic[col + "_" + df.index.strftime("%Y")]
Out: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index

I guess I don't understand how pandas is parsing the df.index value to the dictionary(?). Can this be fixed, or is another approach necessary?

Yes, excuse me, my previous comments were wrong and just trying to find what the problem was, not to provide a solution on how to do what you need. That's why I deleted them. I cannot test any code right now, so cannot post proper suggestions. Good luck with your code. I don't know right now how to solve this.

You can create a Series from your dictionary, then unstack to DataFrame, reindex/set_axis, perform your operation and join with add_suffix:
def split(k):
    x, y = k.split('_')
    return (int(y), x)

# ensure using NaNs for missing values, not strings
df = df.replace('Unk', pd.NA).convert_dtypes()

# reshape to match the original DataFrame
tmp = (pd.Series({split(k): v for k, v in dic.items()})
         .unstack()
         .reindex(df.index.year)  # match years in df.index
         .set_axis(df.index)      # restore full dates
      )

# divide, add_suffix, join
out = df.join(df.div(tmp).add_suffix('1'))
# or
# out = df.join(tmp.rdiv(df), rsuffix='1')

Output:
               A   B        A1        B1
2019-12-31     1   3      0.01     0.015
2020-12-30     2  20  0.016667  0.133333
2020-12-31  <NA>  50      <NA>  0.333333

Intermediate tmp:
              A    B
2019-12-31  100  200
2020-12-30  120  150
2020-12-31  120  150

Variant
Here we rather create a tmp with only the years, and use an intermediate rename step to perform the alignment:
def split(k):
    x, y = k.split('_')
    return (int(y), x)

df = df.replace('Unk', pd.NA).convert_dtypes()

tmp = (pd.Series({split(k): v for k, v in dic.items()})
         .unstack()
      )

out = df.join(df.rename(lambda x: x.year).div(tmp)
                .add_suffix('1').set_axis(df.index)
             )

Intermediate tmp:
        A    B
2019  100  200
2020  120  150


One solution with apply() which runs a given function on each row:
df = df.replace("Unk", np.nan)
df["A1"] = df.apply(lambda row: round(row["A"] / dic["A_" + str(row.name)[:4]], 3) , axis=1)
df["B1"] = df.apply(lambda row: round(row["B"] / dic["B_" + str(row.name)[:4]], 3) , axis=1)
display(df)


PS: row is a series and row.name is actually the index of the dataframe so the date.
